# calabash-android new mail button

Tags: android, calabash

Here is the case, I'm new pie in android and I'm  running an automated test to send an email using calabash-android every 5 minutes from an application installed on android, and in the scenario I can open the email application successfully, but the new email button is marked with an image of an envelope.

Now how can I know the identifier for that button to tell calabash-android to press that button?

I tried to run debug for the emulator and each time I press the new email button I receive this in the debug:

> 11-27 18:36:59.092: I/ActivityManager(1177): START u0 {cmp=com.android.email/com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity (has extras)} from pid 5668

Anyone knows how to get the identifier for that button ??

Answer (score 2):

Every element on the UI has a way to be queried. You might not need the id, as sometimes other characteristics of said element can be used to query it.

Usually, here is how I tackle these problems. Say for example that I want to query an element that shows up on the menu:

1- Fire up calabash's console. You can do so by following these instructions (from calabash's [wiki](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/05-Query-Syntax))

```
krukow:~/tmp/android$ calabash-android console login.apk 
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
=> nil
#You can now query the UI and see the description
```

2- Display the UI that I want to query (in this case, I click the menu button). Then I type in the console:

```
 query("*")
```

This will eventually show all the views on the screen, including some stuff that is not even visible. You simply look for some characteristics of the views you want to query. In my case, I will notice that the views I want is marked with a specific text.

```
 query(" * marked:'More'")
```

Eventually, you could anything from the text inside the view, to its id, to its position. Since `query` returns an array, you could, worst-case, get an element using its index in the array.

If you need help writing the query, try the `query("*")` command and post the result.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, i had a work around to use the dimension for the button. But i will try your solution as well.